# getting Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: "" when calling getBalance from web3 js library

Tags: web3js, json-rpc

I'm exploring web3 following instructions from the docs and running the code below. The function throws with the error message being: Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""

For context the code below works when running a local node script, but gives me the error when running in a Node 8 environment hosted by firebase.

What am I doing wrong and can anyone explain what it means?

```
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<project ID>"))
const weiBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance("0x52bc44d5378309EE2abF1539BF71dE1b7d7bE3b5")
console.log(weiBalance)
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to substitute a specific <project ID> in the first line?

Comment: Just so you know, `web3.eth.getBalance` returns a Promise object, which you need to resolve in order to get the actual balance of the input address.

Comment: yes sorry to not be more specific here. <project ID> serves as a placeholder here I added my id in the actual code. Also I added an await for the promise to resolve. That was not related to the error

Answer (score 1):

Ok i figured this out. Had to upgrade to paid plan in firebase.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/46772)

Comment: @ShaneFontaine It does answer the question: it doesn't work in firebase free tiers.